# ReactNative render nested list slow: Suggestion

Tags: react-native

JSON Structure:

```
sectionItems={key: ..., name: .., title: ..listOf 20 nested data }

data = 
  {
    "sections": [...sectionItems of 50 items]
  }

When displaying in the FlatList its rendering too slow,

<FlatList
  renderItem={({item}) => <Section item={item} />}
  initialNumToRender={lastSelectedItemIndex}
/>
```

Prior to FlatList have used SectionList to render the data but it was too slow to render the data, the requirement is to show all the content in one shot, but FlatList takes too much time to load the items in the viewport, showing more whitespace.

What can be best solution the render a nested list, SectionList or FlatList, the list should have selected item highlighted, so i need to connect to store too.

Answer (score 0):

I just do this by nesting flat lists and taking care of proper rendering within list items. For example I had a list of days, and per each day there were 'entries'. Instead of section list I have a flat list which holds "days list". The day list displays the list header for new day, say 14th January. the rest of this list item is a flat list, containing all the entries for this list. You can highlight easily by making the specific list item wrapped in a touchable. I must render 1000 elements at time and have never had performance issues besides massive updates coming after syncing process. I think this approach might work best for you.

Comment: i'm currently  using nested flatlist, i'm rendering 50 as sections, and each section has 10 - 100 items so some time its taking 3 to 4 sec to render the nested item.

Are you rendering the nested flatlist on onPress or what is done there onPress, can you please explain

Comment: I'm wrapping a single 'entry' in a touchable, catch the onPress and re-render just this particular item to show it is highlighted. To improve the time of your list re-renders (not renders) you can use the shouldComponentUpdate and return a boolean. This way you will avoid re-rendering of the whole list for example when only a single item within it requires re-render.

Comment: I'm rendering the entries data when the dates are clicked and it will be expanded and are you maintaining the clicked state in redux because flatlist is removing the component when its goes out of the view and when i scroll fast its showing more blank spaces, how you are resolving it

Comment: You can limit the number of the loaded list items to just the ones visible to the screen and then automatically load more entries when user reaches the top of the nested list with the flat list method onEndReached. This improved my apps performance. And yes my list is stored in redux, and I persist the list too. Make sure you follow redux immutability rules, if you don't mutate your state right, the list will not update. Good luck!